# Namespace missing

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have following class in folder frontend/migrations

```
use yii\db\Schema;

class m170727_180101_Bewerbungen extends \yii\db\Migration
{
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $tableOptions = null;
        if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
            $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
        }

        $this->createTable('bewerbungen', [
            'bew_id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'datum' => $this->date()->notNull(),
            'firma' => $this->string(100)->notNull(),
            'rechtsart' => $this->integer(11),
            'stadt' => $this->string(100)->notNull(),
            'plz' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
            'strasse_nr' => $this->string(100),
            'ansprech_person' => $this->string(100),
            'email' => $this->string(50)->notNull(),
            'feedback' => $this->integer(11),
            'bemerkungen' => $this->string(150),
            'FOREIGN KEY ([[feedback]]) REFERENCES nachricht ([[id_message]]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE',
            'FOREIGN KEY ([[rechtsart]]) REFERENCES rechtsform ([[id_recht]]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE',
            ], $tableOptions);

    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
        $this->dropTable('bewerbungen');
    }
}
```

Each try to read out method safeUp() throws out error:

> Unable to find 'frontend\migrations\m170727_180101_Bewerbungen' in file: E:\xampp\htdocs\Yii2_Mail/frontend/migrations/m170727_180101_Bewerbungen.php. Namespace missing?**

Here is my script:

```
namespace frontend\migrations; ...

$connect=new m170727_180101_Bewerbungen();
$connect->safeUp(); ...
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

What the hell is that?
The same error using like this:

```
$connect=new \frontend\migrations\m170727_180101_Bewerbungen();
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path

```
 $connect=new \frontend\migration\m170727_180101_Bewerbungen();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got this error because there is no namespace in your file so autoloader can not find it.

But this is not the real problem here - you are not using Yii 2 migration properly. Follow the [Yii2 Migration Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html).

In addition, since you placed this migration in `frontend` you might want to take a look at [Namespaced Migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#namespaced-migrations) to actually add namespace there and to run it properly.